# Python replace a string with wild characters

Tags: python

I have a string like this:

```
 jmeter -t xyz.jmx -Jhost=192.111.11.11 -JCEnext=192.111.11.11 ....
```

`xyz.jmx` is variable string and can be any name i.e `abc123.jmx` or `xyz1.jmx` ..

I need to replace

```
jmeter -t xyz.jmx
```

with

```
jmeter -n -t C:\Automation\Jmeter\xyz.jmx
```

how can I do this?

Comment: And what about the other parameters? `-Jhost` and so on. Should those stay, or be removed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Regex**: using `re.sub`

**Ex:**

```
import re
s = "jmeter -t xyz.jmx -Jhost=192.111.11.11 -JCEnext=192.111.11.11"
toReplace = r"jmeter -n -t C:\Automation\Jmeter\\"

print(re.sub("jmeter(.*?)\-t\s+", toReplace, s))
```

**Output:**

```
jmeter -n -t C:\Automation\Jmeter\xyz.jmx -Jhost=192.111.11.11 -JCEnext=192.111.11.11
```

Comment: I tried it but the result is this:  jmeter -n -t C:\Automation\Jmeter\xyz.jmxzyz.jmx     how can I get rid of extra xyz.jmx at the end

Comment: This worked  str2 = re.sub("jmeter(.*?)\-t\s+(.*?)\.jmx", toReplace, s)

Comment: You probably had the filename in the toreplace variable. `toReplace = r"jmeter -n -t C:\Automation\Jmeter\xyz.jmx"` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Positive Lookbehind (?<=-t)`

```
import re

pattern =r'(?<=-t)\s(\w.+?\s)'

text='jmeter -t xyz.jmx -Jhost=192.111.11.11 -JCEnext=192.111.11.11 ....'

replaced=re.sub(pattern,r' C:\Automation\Jmeter\xyz.jmx ',text)
print(replaced)
```

output:

```
jmeter -t C:\Automation\Jmeter\xyz.jmx -Jhost=192.111.11.11 -JCEnext=192.111.11.11 ....
```